# Basic SQL query help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 colums. *Here is an example with just a few entries to demo. The table represents the dates that an item's price changes. I need a query that will tell me the prices for all the items on a specific date. The specific date may be between price changes. The price changes at midnight, so the date of the change, that is the price from then until and on the day before the previous change*:

```
itemCode  datePriceEffective  price  
AB         2012-01-01          9.99  
AB         2012-03-02          10.50  
XY         2011-09-20          34.99
```

I wish to get all the items prices for a given date. There is not an entry for every date, just the dates that the price changes.
so 2012-03-05 would return

```
AB 10.50
XY 34.99
```

and 2012-02-27 would return:

```
AB 9.99  
XY 34.99
```

The SQL query needed to get this escapes me. Answers appreciated.

Edited as answers are going in wrong direction see italics for edit.

Comment: do you have another column with dates? Because the dates you mention in the query are not to be seen in any column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to join back to the table as follows:

```
declare @effdate datetime
set @effdate = CONVERT(datetime,'2012-02-27')

;WITH CTE_DATA as (
    select itemCode='AB',  datePriceEffective = CONVERT(Datetime,'2012-01-01'),  price = 9.99
    union all select itemCode='AB',  datePriceEffective = CONVERT(Datetime,'2012-03-02'),  price = 10.50
    union all select itemCode='XY',  datePriceEffective = CONVERT(Datetime,'2011-09-20'),  price = 34.99
)
select
    d.itemcode,
    price
from
    CTE_DATA d
    join (
        select  
            itemcode,
            effdate = MAX(datepriceeffective)
        from CTE_DATA sub where sub.datepriceeffective <= @effdate
        group by itemcode
    ) x
        on x.itemCode = d.itemCode
        and x.effdate = d.datePriceEffective
```

Note that the CTE is just for this example, you should swap it for your real table.

UPDATE: An alternative approach is to use ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION as follows:

```
SELECT        
    itemcode,
    price
FROM     
   (
        SELECT   
            itemcode,
            price,
            rowno = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by itemcode order by datePriceEffective desc)
        from
            CTE_DATA
            where datePriceEffective <= @effdate
    ) x
where 
    rowno = 1
```

(Substitute this select for the one in the previous query to try it out on the data)

Comment: this looks uneccesarily complicated.

Comment: The CTE is just to generate some data to run on. The actual queries are simple enough. Nikola's solution is similar to my 2nd answer, but filters the required results more neatly.

Answer (score 3):

This retrieves first record by descending order of datePriceEffective per itemCode.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from ATable
where datePriceEffective <= @givenDate
order by row_number() over (partition by itemCode 
                            order by datePriceEffective desc)
```

Comment: +1: That's a great use of `WITH TIES` - gives a really neat solution!.

Comment: this works thanks. Though not the first, so missed out on the accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT itemCode,price FRom TableNameHere WHERE datePriceEffective <= '2012-03-05'
```

---

Edit after more info - a 'simple' answer to hopefully make it easy to follow.

You're getting thelatest date for the item that is valid in your required date range and then joining the table to itself to get the price at that date

```
SELECT t1.itemCode,t1.price FROM 
  (
  SELECT itemCode,MAX(datePriceEffective) AS datePriceEffective
  FROM TableNameHere
  WHERE datePriceEffective <= '2012-03-05'
  ) a
INNER JOIN TableNameHere t1 ON t1.itemCode = a.itemCode AND t1.datePriceEffective = a.datePriceEffective
```

Comment: Sorry, yes you listed that date in your question then edited your question to explain what you are after...

Comment: Provided the datePriceEffective is a datetime column you can use less than and greater than operators.

Comment: Yes this looks more like it but this will likely bring back multiple prices for one item prior to that date.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date datetime = '2012-03-05'

select distinct itemcode,
    (
        select top(1) itemprice 
        from mytable mt2 
        where 
            mt1.itemcode = mt2.itemcode and
            mt2.datepriceeffective <= @date
        order by datepriceeffective desc
    ) as itemprice
from 
    mytable mt1
where
    datepriceeffective <= @date
```

Comment: this works thanks. Though not the first, so missed out on the accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.itemCode, 
(SELECT Price FROM dbo.tblProducts a WHERE datePriceEffective = 
(SELECT MAX(a.datePriceEffective) FROM dbo.tblProducts a WHERE a.itemCode = b.itemCode)) AS Price
FROM dbo.tblProducts b
WHERE b.datePriceEffective <= '2012-03-05'
GROUP BY b.itemCode
```

I have tested it! It will give you the most updated price for each Item

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have another column called 'GivenDate', below is the query.

```
SELECT itemCode, price
FROM tblName
WHERE GivenDate= '2012-03-05'
```

Comment: do you have to use datePriceEffective column to get the results for the given date? And the datePriceEffective gets updated frequently?

Comment: If this is the case then you can query on the dates present in the datePriceEffective column. You cannot use any 'Other' given date.

Answer (score 0):

This works on sql2000

```
SELECT      s.itemCode
            , ( SELECT      TOP 1 price
                FROM        #MyTable
                WHERE       itemCode = s.itemCode
                            AND datePriceEffective < @SearchDate ) AS price
FROM        (
            SELECT DISTINCT itemCode 
            FROM   #MyTable
            ) s
```